# Questions about grammar in sentences

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which sounds correct:

> You cannot watch the Star Trek films without having seen the TV series.

Or:

> Having seen the TV Series, then you can watch the Star Trek films.

I do not understand why these two constructions do not mean the same thing.

.....................................

> He admitted **having stolen** the money.

Or:

> First he was stealing, then he admitted it.

Are my sentences right? If not, please correct my original sentences.

Comment: Be very careful about asking "are these sentences correct?" without identifying why you think they might be wrong. We are not, and we cannot become, a free proofreading service. Questions should identify which parts of the sentence you are having trouble with, and tell why you're unsure of their correctness.

Answer (score 1):

This one is better

> You cannot watch the Star Trek films without having seen the TV series.

if you mean to explain that it is impossible to understand the films without having seen the TV series.

The second sentence would have to be amended to mean the same:

> Having seen the TV Series, you can now enjoy the Star Trek films more (than if you hadn't).

---

The other two are not really related.

> He admitted having stolen the money

is correct on its own

> First he was stealing, then he admitted it

does not immediately look correct. It is correct syntactically, but depending on context perhaps not what you mean

> First he stole, then he admitted it

is perhaps better

Comment: Thank you so much and I am so sorry if I did not identify my question

Comment: You cannot watch the Star Trek films without having seen the TV series.
Or:

Having seen the TV Series, then you can watch the Star Trek films. However, I can not understand the reason why these are not the same?

Comment: The second sentence does not mean the same, and the "then" does not work

Comment: You can only say "Having seen the TV series, you can now..." to someone who's seen the TV series, probably recently.